# Need to upload file in Cypress

Tags: automation

I want to upload file to my website while doing automation testing using cypress. I have stored my PDf file in 'Fixtures' folder of cypress. In code, I am getting error message when 'fileContent' function is called. Below is the code:

```
cy.fixture('certificate.pdf', 'base64').then(fileContent => {
        cy.get('.file-upload-btn').upload(
            {
                fileName: 'certificate.pdf',
                mimeType: 'pdf'
            },
            {
                uploadType: 'input'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you save your file in the fixture, you have also to add this part in the file `commands.js` under the folder support:

```
import 'cypress-file-upload';
```

After, you can try this:

```
cy.fixture(fileName).then(fileContent => {
  cy.get('#subject_profile_import_file').upload({ fileContent, fileName, mimeType: 'application/pdf' }, { subjectType: 'input' })
})
```

Comment: i added command in 'command.js' file and then added following code:

```cy.fixture('certificate.pdf').then(fileContent => {
            cy.get('.file-upload-btn').upload(
                {
                    fileContent,
                    fileName: 'certificate.pdf',
                    mimeType: 'application/pdf'
                },
                {
                    subjectType: 'input'
                });```

Still unable to upload file. Getting error on function.